# Does there exist any proper subgroup $(H,+)$ of $(\mathbb Q,+)$ such that $H$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ ?

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory

Does there exist any proper subgroup $(H,+)$ of $(\mathbb Q,+)$ such that $H$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fractions whose denominator is a power of two are the elements of a subgroup which is dense.

Comment: oh yes , true ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

let $q_n$ be *any* sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $q_n \to 0$. then the set $\{q_1,q_2,...\}$ generates a dense subgroup. put this way the interesting question is to state the conditions which guarantee that the generated group is a *proper* subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$